# Modular Angular structure with Browserify

Tags: javascript, angular.js, modules

I am trying to create a basic angular template where all files are sorted into a modular structure and referenced using the browserify require method.

I am very new to browserify and the CommonJS-type import system.

Here is a look at the initial structure before I go into details of the file contents:

[image]

So to start I have the app folder which contains all the Angular JS files.

"bundle.js" is the output from browserify. This is what will be referenced from the index.html file.

In this I have the app.module.js file which is the main angular app file. This is the file which browserify uses as the start point.

So far "app.module.js" contains the following:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');
require('./components/');

var app = angular.module('app', [require('ui-router'), 'app.home', 'app.other']);
app.config(require("./app.routes"));
app.constant('VERSION', require('../../package.json').version);
```

**app.routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
}
```

Then in each sub folder I have an index.js which is used by browserify when the require is called for that folder.

**app/components/index.js** just references all the components:

```
'use strict';
require("./home/");
require("./other/");
```

**app/components/home/index.js:**

```
module.exports = require("angular")
    .module("app.home", [])
    .config(require("./home.routes"))
    .controller("homeController", require("./home.controller"));
```

**home.controller.js:**

```
module.exports = function($scope)
{
    $scope.message = "Loaded home controller!";
};
```

**home.routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            "": {
                templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.view.html",
                controller: "homeController"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**home.view.html:**

```
<section>
    {{message}}
</section>
```

"home.service.js" is empty and not used, but you get the idea.

The structure is the same for the `other` folder.